# How to add bootstrap to Django Form,py?

Tags: django

I want to add bootstrap style to my radio buttons however I do not know how to do this.

This is my form:

```
class GenderForm(forms.ModelForm):
CHOICES=[('Male','0'),('Female','1')]
Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = ['Gender']
```

I am calling the form as follows:

```
<form action="{% url 'gender'%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Gender</legend>
  {{ Gen_form|crispy}}
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

-->

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
class GenderForm(forms.ModelForm):
CHOICES=[('Male','0'),('Female','1')]
Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
   'class': 'CSS CLASS THAT YOU NEED FOR IT',
}))

class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = ['Gender']
```